# How to convert mouse movements to rotation of an element

Tags: math, rotation, degrees, radians

I'm building a wheel menu control. The idea is you spin the wheel until the item you want to act on is in view, then you click on it or whatever. I'm trying to figure out how to translate the user's mouse movements (x & y) into the number of degrees to spin the wheel. I can implement it all, I just am missing the math to do the conversion. Any help or pointers are appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image: Angle between mouse positions]

If the user moves the mouse from [x1,y1] to [x2,y2], what you basically want is to find

θ=θ<sub>1</sub>-θ<sub>2</sub>

Where:

θ<sub>1</sub> = Math.atan2(y1, x1);

θ<sub>2</sub> = Math.atan2(y2, x2);

Now all of this depends on where you define your origin (center of your wheel).  If your origin is [x0,y0], then just subtract those values from the actual mouse co-ordinates.

Also on screen, the co-ordinate system is upside down, so 0,0 is in the top-left instead of bottom-left, so you'd need to flip that, but the math is essentially the same.

Also note that the angle is measured in radians and not degrees.

Answer (score 1):

Take the `atan2()` of two subsequent positions offset from the center of the control and change the value by the delta of the angles multiplied by a constant.

Comment: @Christian: Because it turns x and y offset into an angle.

Comment: I was with you until the end. Multiplied by what constant?

Comment: The constant you determine with experimental analysis that converts the delta angle into delta translation on the menu.